# Как вывести определённый элемент в smarty?

Tags: php, smarty, шаблонизаторы

Здравствуйте. Есть код для формирования сообщения на e-mail с помощью smarty v2.

```
{strip}
{#ANKETA_LETTER_INFO#|sprintf:$data.name}: http://{$data.path.domain}{$data.path.uri}{"\n"}
{"\n"}
{foreach from=$data.dictionaries key=ready item=e name=number}
{if $e.value != ""}
    {$ready+1}:{$e.name|htmlspecialchars_decode|strip_tags}:{" "}
        {if $e.type_code == 'UPLOAD'}
            {foreach from=$e.uploaded item=ee name=foo}
                {$ee.url}
                {if !$smarty.foreach.foo.last}{"\n"}{/if}
            {/foreach}
        {elseif $e.type_code == 'CHECKBOX'}
            {if $e.value == $e.name}{#ON#}{else}{$e.value}{/if} 
        {else}
            {$e.value}
        {/if}
        {"\n"}
{/if}       
{/foreach}
{"\n"}
{if isset($data.result.referer)}
{"\n"}{"\n"}
{$data.result.referer|replace:"\n\n":"\n"|nl2br}
{/if}

{if isset($data.result.i)}
{"\n"}{"\n"}
{$data.result.i|nl2br}
{"\n"}
{/if}

{#ANKETA_LETTER_NOTE#}
{/strip}
```

Как мне вывести определённый элемент {$e.name|htmlspecialchars_decode|strip_tags}:{" "} по индексу ?

Comment: в смысле? у вас есть ключ массива `$ready` и соответствующий элемент `$e`. Что вы хотите вывести и по какому индексу?

Comment: Мне нужно вывести не число, а именно третий элемент, как это сделать ?

Comment: а где у вас число? если вам не нужен цикл, то не используйте его. доступ  к элементам осуществляется как и всегда `$data.dictionaries[3]`зы: `isset()` можно и не использовать

Comment: Если делаю  $data.dictionaries[3], то пишет Array

Comment: ну правильно, это же массив у вас `$data.dictionaries[3].name`, `.value`, `.type_code` у вас там внутри элемента

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял.